# How do I get SchemaCrawler to export actual table row data to the text output?

Tags: database-schema, snapshot, schemacrawler

How do I get [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) to export actual table row data to the text output?  I can't find a example anywhere, nor documentation that refers to this option, although I have seen references on the internet implying that it can be done.   I am able to export information about the schema, but it is just missing the data.

I'm using the Oracle version of SchemaCrawler.  I'm using  **schemacrawler.config.properties** but I cannot find a list anywhere of all the possible options.   The command I use is like this:

```
java.exe -classpath lib/*;. schemacrawler.tools.oracle.Main -infolevel=maximum
-database=%5 -g=schemacrawler.config.properties -user=%1 -password=%2 
-schemas=%5 -port=%4 -host=%3 -table_types=TABLE -command="SELECT * FROM %5.%6" 
-sortcolumns=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
java.exe -classpath lib/*;. schemacrawler.tools.oracle.Main -infolevel=maximum
-database=%5 -g=schemacrawler.config.properties -user=%1 -password=%2 
-schemas=%5 -port=%4 -host=%3 -table_types=TABLE -command=dump 
-sortcolumns=true
```

or this (see enclosing quotes for the command)

```
java.exe -classpath lib/*;. schemacrawler.tools.oracle.Main -infolevel=maximum
-database=%5 -g=schemacrawler.config.properties -user=%1 -password=%2 
-schemas=%5 -port=%4 -host=%3 -table_types=TABLE "-command=SELECT * FROM %5.%6" 
-sortcolumns=true
```

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler

Comment: Thanks, that probably helped me a little.  You answer wasn't exact but I definitely got it working.  Here is my resulting code:  https://gist.github.com/djangofan/9997619  . YOu should include this batch script as an example in your examples.